# Extra line between fileInput and checkboxInput in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

It looks like there is an extra space between fileInput and checkboxInput in Shiny (even though I do not add an extra line). How do I get rid of that extra line? Thanks!

```
if (interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
        accept = c(
          "text/csv",
          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
          ".csv")
        ),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    inFile <- input$file1    
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)    
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is the space for the progress bar. You can remove the margins of the surrounding elements with CSS, by loading package `shinyjs` and inserting this anywhere in your UI:

```
inlineCSS(list(".shiny-input-container" = "margin-bottom: 0px", 
               "#file1_progress" = "margin-bottom: 0px", 
               ".checkbox" = "margin-top: 0px"))
```

or, if you want to do native CSS without extra package:

```
      tags$style(".shiny-input-container {margin-bottom: 0px} #file1_progress { margin-bottom: 0px } .checkbox { margin-top: 0px}"),
```

Tipp: right-click on the space you want to remove and choose "Inspect element". You then see to which node of the HTML the space belongs.

[image]